# Error when integrate Sinch third-party library in Swift?

Tags: swift3, sinch

I want to build the video call function in my app and i decided to choose Sinch framework. But when i press the call, seem the `localView` can not track. Please help me how to fix this. Thank a lot. Here is my code get error:

```
func videoController() -> SINVideoController {
   let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   return (appDel.client?.videoController())!
}
```

I got this error in `return` line:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102bcc740)
```

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sinCall?.delegate = self

    playSound()

    if sinCall?.direction == SINCallDirection.incoming { 
        lbReceiverName.text = "Đang gọi"
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateLabelForReceiver), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        if let id = senderName {
            databaseRefenrence.child("Users").child("\(id)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                    self.lbDangGoi.text = dict["Name"] as? String
                }
            })
        }
        localView.isHidden = false
        btAccept.isHidden = false
        btDecline.isHidden = false
        btEnd.isHidden = true
    } else {
        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateLabelForSender), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        if let name = receiverName {
            lbReceiverName.text = name
        }
        localView.isHidden = false
        btAccept.isHidden = true
        btDecline.isHidden = true
        btEnd.isHidden = false
    }

    if sinCall?.details.isVideoOffered == true {
        localView.addSubview((videoController().localView())!)
    }
}

func callDidAddVideoTrack(_ call: SINCall!) {
    remoteView.addSubview((videoController().remoteView())!)
}
```

Comment: What does the log say more? Is the client started succesfully? Can you share the setup/init code in the app delegate?

Comment: thank for your comment. I do not set up code on delegate. I set up it on the view has the call button

Comment: the audio is connected but the local and remote view still not appear?, so how can to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: do you see the remoteView and localView at all in your view? try not to hide them to start with .

Comment: and how are you setting sincall    sinCall?.delegate = self seems a bit to early, are you setting that in anohter controller

Comment: is callDidAddVideoTrack being called at all?

Comment: I fixed it already, i think the error is that i did not init the client. Thanks you so much for your helping